# After phone number validation from Digits by twitter, I am getting two instance of my app in recent activity

Tags: android, android-activity, multiple-instances, twitter-fabric

Hiii, I have looked on Digits documentation over and over for this fix but couldn't find it. Whenever I open Digit mobile validation screen and then close it, I am getting two instance of my app in recent screen.

Here is how I am setting up Digits.

On Application,

```
Fabric.with(this,  new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits());
```

And at activity,

```
DigitsAuthButton digitsButton = (DigitsAuthButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_phone_auth);
digitsButton.setAuthTheme(R.style.CustomDigitsTheme);
AuthCallback authCallback = new AuthCallback() {
        @Override
        public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
            //validated number processing
    };
digitsButton.setCallback(authCallback);
```

Need help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is been resolved in Digits v1.10.0.

```
compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.10.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Comment: hey, Abhishek still there is multiple instance of app..  is there other way to fix this?

Comment: I am not getting this issue from v1.10.0, perhaps you should try latest version v1.11.0.

Comment: well, i have to search for other alternatives as i have tried with 1.11 but not worked for me.

Comment: Other than that I have not done anything and my issue got resolved.